# How to disable default Google analytics virtual page record

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, single-page-application

I have implemented Google Analytic virtual page view in my single page web application. It loads directly by typing URL(www.mysite.com) and some views are loading by adding URL parameters to the site URL(www.mysite.com/?formtype=A&title=Bar).
The problem is I can see some records in my virtual page view table like follows.

1. /
2. /?formtype=A&title=Bar

But I have not implemented these virtual page events in my code.
I do not need these two page view events in my record. Can any one please help me to solve this?

This is how the implementation of GA in my index page.

```
        <script>
            (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
                i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
                    (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
                }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
                    m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
            })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

            ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxx-x', 'auto');

        </script>
```

Comment: This is definitely not all of your code because, based on what you've shown, you're not sending any data to Google Analytics. Where is your event tracking code?

Comment: ga('set', {
            page: '/index',
            title: 'My Home'
        });
        ga('send', 'pageview'); this is how I send data to the GA. There are lot of virtual page event implemented like this inside my javascript code.They are firing as I expected.But above two events are firing with out any implementation.

Answer (score 1):

If you're seeing pageview hits for those URLs, then somewhere in your code you're sending those hits. I'd recommend using the [Google Analytics Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en) Chrome Extension or the [analytics_debug.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#debug) version of the script to help you understand exactly what you're sending to GA.

I'd also recommend reading the [Tracking Single Page Applications](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications) developer guide. It will tell you exactly what you need to know to track applications like yours. You've used the word "events" a lot in your question, and events are not needs to track SPAs, so I suspect reading that developer guide will be very helpful.